# added two search bar in django one search by id and other by name .Tried many ways but cannot do it if i try by id then i am not able to do with name

Tags: python, django, web, searchbar

I have to make 2 search bars. I don't know how to add multiple fiels...
`match= Staff.objects.filter(id=srch1...)` here how can I add `name=srch1`
over here after trying many ways I found it but the problem is all input here is string how to change it to int

```
def search(request):
     # Catch the data and search in Staff model.
    if request.method=='POST':
        srch1 = request.POST['srch']
        print(type(srch1))
        if type(srch1)== int:
            match= Staff.objects.filter(id=srch1)
            if match :
                return render(request,'search.html',{'sr': match})
            else:
                messages.error(request,'no results,found')
        elif type(srch1)== str:
            catch= Staff.objects.filter(name=srch1)
            if catch:
                return render(request,'search.html',{'sr': catch})
            else:
                messages.error(request,'no results,found')
        else:

            return HttpResponseRedirect("/search")
    return render(request,"search.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a GET request with querysting parameters or (url parameters, which is a bit more complicated) for this, not a POST. Here's how I would do this:

```
def search(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Initial empty query dictionary for use with query later.
    query = {}
    # Getting 'name' and 'id' from querystring parameters (i.e. ?id=1&name=foo)
    name = request.GET.get('name', None)
    id = request.GET.get('id', None)
    # Add 'id' to the query dictionary if it exists
    if id is not None:
        query['id'] = id
    # Add name to the query dictionary if it exists
    if name is not None:
        query['name'] = name
    # If the query dictionary has name or id, get the Staff entry from the database
    if query.get('name', None) or query.get('id', None):
        # Note that .filter() returns a QuerySet. You should probably use .get()
        # since my guess is that you only want one Staff object (judging by your      
        # search parameters). Also note that since we are using **query we will be
        # using BOTH 'name' AND 'id' to search for the Staff, as long as both exist in 
        # the query dictionary.
        match = Staff.objects.get(**query)
        # If there is a match, send it in the rendered response context dict
        if match:
           return render(request, 'search.html', {'sr': match})
        # no match, send message notifying that a Staff entry was not found matching
        # the desired criteria
        return render(request, 'search.html', {message: 'Not Found'}
    # There were no query parameters, so we are not searching for anything.
    else:
        return render(request, 'search.html')
```

You can see that the above code is much simpler, and more concise. This will help you or anyone else checking out your code in the future to better understand what you're trying to acheive.

P.S. I typically only use POST requests when I am *creating an entry in the database*. Maybe this is preference, but to my knowledge it is best practice to use a GET request for search.

Comment: no details are appearing on the page after using this code